# How to decode videoData from ios in opencv videocapture

Tags: python, ios, sockets, opencv, h.264

I have an Objective-C app that I get in a function video data as 
`unit8_t.bytes` and length.

```
    -(void)videoFeed:(DJIVideoFeed *)videoFeed didUpdateVideoData: 
   (NSData *)videoData {
        [[DJIVideoPreviewer instance] push:(uint8_t *)videoData.bytes length:(int)videoData.length];
        [_videoExtractor parseVideo:(uint8_t *)videoData.bytes 
    length:(int)videoData.length withFrame:^(VideoFrameH264Raw *frame) {
```

I have `SocketIO` implemented in the application and I send this data to a python server with `OpenCV` on it .

I have 2 problems:

1. I don't know how to take this data and actually make it a video
2. I wish to send `h264` throw the socket but the type(`VideoFrameH264Raw`) is not expectable by Objective-C

   ```
   [self.socket emit:@"streaming" with:@[frame]];
   ```

I have tried to get the information in videocapture in OpenCV but with no lack , 
I am also a little bit confuse about the case i get single frames throw the socket and show them as a video in python.

Answer (score -1):

Emm depends on how it is encoded.

If it using the internal encoder (.mov), not much you can do now. It is a proprietary compression algorithm. And apple doesn't give a crap about a single researcher

If it is DJI internal data feed, they are using FFMPEG like method. Shouldn't have many problems in setting using UDP server capture way.

To confirm this, You can try with H264 directly. Or you can try to see the raw video data? For mp4 there was a few bits/bytes of key control sequence.

Comment: thank you, but dji encapsulate there ffmpeg functionality, so i sont have an idea how to   setting UDP server capture.

Comment: Please use workplace-appropriate language on Stack Overflow, not language which may be offensive to some groups of people. Please see: [Are expletives (cursing, swear words, vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites) Keep in mind that using offensive language tends to result in people reacting poorly to your posts (i.e. they may downvote). In addition, do you really want a future employer to see you using such language in a situation which is intended to be professional?